# Как удалить определенное словосочетание со страницы?

Tags: javascript, php

Как удалить определенное словосочетание со страницы через PHP/JS из структуры DOM?

Comment: Получить все данные из базы, найти регуляркой и заменить, сохранить в базу обратно. Либо заменить сразу в базе

Comment: @lezhni а есть способ сделать это через код?

Comment: DOM - это модель отпарсеного браузером документа. И ничего удалить из него с помощью PHP уже нельзя, только на момент генерации страницы. А вот с помощью JS можно обойти все элементы документа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block_del").html(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp("мимолетное виденье", 'g'), "<span class=del>Удалили нужное</span>")
  });
});
```

```css
.del {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Удаляем определенное словосочетание "мимолетное виденье"</h4>
<div class="block">
  <p>Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br> Передо мной явилась ты,<br> Как мимолетное виденье,<br> Как гений чистой красоты.</p>
</div>
<div class="block_del">
  <p>Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br> Передо мной явилась ты,<br> Как мимолетное виденье,<br> Как гений чистой красоты.</p>
</div>
```